# Coverting strings from a text file to integers

Tags: python, file

```
[0, 1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11],[12, 13, 14, 15],[16, 17, 18, 19, 20],[21, 22, 23]
[0, 1, 2],[3, 4, 5],[6, 7, 8, 9],[10, 11, 12, 13]

[0, 1],[2],[3, 4, 5],[6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6, 7],[8],[9, 10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15]
```

I have the above text file. The problem is that each of the indexes in this file are a string but I want to convert them back to integers.
I tried this:

```
with open("abc.txt", "r") as text_file:
    new_list = [int(line) for line in text_file]
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[0, 1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11],[12, 13, 14, 15],[16, 17, 18, 19, 20],[21, 22, 23]\n'
```

Output-

```
[0, 1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11],[12, 13, 14, 15],[16, 17, 18, 19, 20],[21, 22, 23]
[0, 1, 2],[3, 4, 5],[6, 7, 8, 9],[10, 11, 12, 13]

[0, 1],[2],[3, 4, 5],[6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6, 7],[8],[9, 10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15]
```

Just that all these lines represent lists containing INTEGERS.

Comment: You could read each line, wrap it in `[]`, and pass it to `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `literal_eval` and `chain`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from itertools import chain

with open("abc.txt", "r") as text_file:
    new_lines = (list(literal_eval(line)) for line in text_file if line.strip())
    new_list = list(chain(*new_lines))
```

`line.strip()` is to skip empty line.

Comment: Hey, but this program removes all the brackets from the end- I require the brackets to stay:

Comment: @sugu Can you edit the problem to give an expected output?

Comment: @sugu still text format... Can you represent them with list? I am still not sure the format of list that you really want.

Comment: That's the format that I want.. The input are from a text file and hence it's of the string format- i want to convert it to a list but the brackets should remain in the same place

Comment: @sugu okay, I try to make a guess. is it what you want?

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you please modify the program a bit so that it takes one line at a time?

Comment: @sugu One line will be hard to read. If you want, you can change it to one line. I tend to keep two line :-)

Answer (score 3):

Read about [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Try this,

```
import ast
with open("abc.txt", "r") as text_file:
    new_list = [list(ast.literal_eval(line)) for line in text_file if line.strip()]
```

---

**Output:**

```
[[[0, 1, 2, 3],  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],  [9, 10, 11],  [12, 13, 14, 15],  [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],  [21, 22, 23]],
 [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]],
 [[0, 1], [2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]],
 [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]]
```

Comment: This will produce a list of tuples, except for lines that only contain a single list, in which case the nesting level will be one less.  Better to wrap the line in `[]` *before* passing it to `literal_eval`.  That will fix all of the bugs, with each line being contained in a single top-level list.

Comment: In this list indices are list not integer though

Comment: For some reason this raises a malformed string error

Comment: File "<unknown>", line 1 SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
It gives this error

Comment: @shaikmoeed have you tested this yourself with the file sugu has given? It won't work because you aren't checking for blank lines and `literal_eval` will throw `SyntaxError` as mentioned above

Comment: @sugu That is what you want?

Comment: @StamKaly Yeah, made changes accordingly. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is your best bet once you've read the data like that,

```
z = re.findall("[\d]+",your_string)
```

Then what's left is to convert each string in the list to an integer, here's a straightforward example,

```
for i in range(len(z)): 
    new_z[i] = int(z[i])
```